# Functionality of probability=TRUE in svm function of e1071 package in R

Tags: r, svm

In R, what is the functionality of `probability=TRUE` in the `svm` function of the `e1071` package?

```
model <- svm (Type ~ ., data, probability=TRUE, cost = 100, gamma = 1)
```

Comment: svm isn't in base R - please mention which package(s) you are using.

Comment: From `?svm` "probability: indicating whether the model should allow for probability predictions."

Comment: I use `e1071` package.

Comment: @user3681744 Add it to the question.  People should get all relevant information from reading the question itself - they shouldn't have to dig into the comments.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Setting the `probability` argument to `TRUE` for both model fitting and prediction returns, for each prediction, the vector of probabilities of belonging to each class of the response variable. These are stored in a matrix, as an attribute of the prediction object.

For example:

```
library(e1071)

model <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris, probability=TRUE)
# (below I'm just predicting to the training dataset - it could of course just 
# as easily be a separate test dataset)
pred <- predict(model, iris, probability=TRUE)

head(attr(pred, "probabilities"))

#      setosa versicolor   virginica
# 1 0.9803339 0.01129740 0.008368729
# 2 0.9729193 0.01807053 0.009010195
# 3 0.9790435 0.01192820 0.009028276
# 4 0.9750030 0.01531171 0.009685342
# 5 0.9795183 0.01164689 0.008834838
# 6 0.9740730 0.01679643 0.009130620
```

Note, however, that it's important to set `probability=TRUE` for the call to `svm`, and not *just* the call to `predict`, since the latter alone would produce:

```
#      setosa versicolor virginica
# 1 0.3333333  0.3333333 0.3333333
# 2 0.3333333  0.3333333 0.3333333
# 3 0.3333333  0.3333333 0.3333333
# 4 0.3333333  0.3333333 0.3333333
# 5 0.3333333  0.3333333 0.3333333
# 6 0.3333333  0.3333333 0.3333333
```

Comment: i get only NULL when i access the attribute, also i get a binary output, where as im expecting probabilities

Comment: @bicepjai under what circumstances?? When you run the code in my post above?

Comment: no ur code gives correct output, my code with my data (binary predictor and other factor and numeric independent variables) gives just binary numbers and not probabilities.

Comment: @bicepjai are you sure you are using `probability=TRUE` in the `predict` call? If so, (and if it's not already been asked) you might need to post a new question with an example that reproduces your problem. It's too hard to work out where things have gone wrong from comments.

Comment: Is that a natural result of a Support Vector Machine or an add-on by the library?

Comment: How are those probabilities calculated in training and prediction? Is it done by fitting a logistic regression on the SVM scores (the signed distance from each point to the separating hyperplane)?

Comment: @bicepjai 's problem : Make sure your outcome variable is coded as a factor. The `"probabilities"` attribute was `NULL` for me because my outcome variable was numeric instead of factor. After the change to factor it worked fine.

Comment: @panc It seems so, from the [docs](https://rdrr.io/cran/e1071/man/svm.html): "The probability model for classification fits a logistic distribution using maximum likelihood to the decision values of all binary classifiers, and computes the a-posteriori class probabilities for the multi-class problem using quadratic optimization."